# How do I animate a rectangle in JavaScript/Canvas without leaving a trail?

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm attempting to create an animation of a rectangle moving down the screen using javascript/canvas.

The problem I'm having is that it moves the rectangle, but leaves a trail behind it instead of just moving the rectangle. (fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/winterswebs/hmgfwp9z/116/)

How do I animate an object without leaving a trail?

```js
let v = {
  movingObjects: [{
    path: new Path2D(),
    y: 0,
    img: {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    }
  }],
  animationTime: 0,
  lastFrameTime: 0,
  testingCountOut: 0,
}

const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

function loop() {

  //if (v.testingCountOut >= 10) return;
  let now = Date.now();
  let delta = v.lastFrameTime == 0 ? 0 : (now - v.lastFrameTime) / 1000;
  v.lastFrameTime = now;
  draw(delta);
  //v.testingCountOut++;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function draw(delta) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  v.animationTime = Number(v.animationTime) + Number(delta);
  let movingObjVY = 100;
  let movingObjYPos = v.animationTime * movingObjVY;

  v.movingObjects.forEach((element, index) => {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    v.movingObjects[index].path.rect(
      10,
      element.y + movingObjYPos,
      element.img.width,
      element.img.height
    );
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)";
    ctx.fill(v.movingObjects[index].path);
    //ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    //ctx.stroke(v.movingObjects[index].path);
    ctx.restore();
  });
}

loop();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your usage of that `path` object is really weird, and the source of your issues - you add a new rectangle to the path you're drawing with each iteration. Why do you even store the path instead of simple creating a new rectangle on every `draw`?

Comment: Yea... I agree it is kinda weird; I wanted it stored so I can reference it in combination with isPointInPath (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) for collision detection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `v.movingObjects[index].path.rect();` you add a new rectangle to the path, that's why you also see all the previous rectangles. You have two options here: either you create a new Path everytime you add the rectangle to the path or you get rid of the path and use the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillRect()` function to simply draw a rectangle on your canvas.

ctx.fillRect() doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect

Option 1 (reset Path2D):

```js
let v = {
  movingObjects: [{
    path: new Path2D(),
    y: 0,
    img: {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    }
  }],
  animationTime: 0,
  lastFrameTime: 0,
  testingCountOut: 0,
}

const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

function loop() {

  //if (v.testingCountOut >= 10) return;
  let now = Date.now();
  let delta = v.lastFrameTime == 0 ? 0 : (now - v.lastFrameTime) / 1000;
  v.lastFrameTime = now;
  draw(delta);
  //v.testingCountOut++;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function draw(delta) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  v.animationTime = Number(v.animationTime) + Number(delta);
  let movingObjVY = 100;
  let movingObjYPos = v.animationTime * movingObjVY;

  v.movingObjects.forEach((element, index) => {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    v.movingObjects[index].path.rect(
      10,
      element.y + movingObjYPos,
      element.img.width,
      element.img.height
    );
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)";
    ctx.fill(v.movingObjects[index].path);
    ctx.closePath();
    v.movingObjects[index].path = new Path2D();
    ctx.restore();
  });
}

loop();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Option 2 (fillRect):

```js
let v = {
  movingObjects: [{
    y: 0,
    img: {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    }
  }],
  animationTime: 0,
  lastFrameTime: 0,
  testingCountOut: 0,
}

const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

function loop() {

  //if (v.testingCountOut >= 10) return;
  let now = Date.now();
  let delta = v.lastFrameTime == 0 ? 0 : (now - v.lastFrameTime) / 1000;
  v.lastFrameTime = now;
  draw(delta);
  //v.testingCountOut++;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

function draw(delta) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  v.animationTime = Number(v.animationTime) + Number(delta);
  let movingObjVY = 100;
  let movingObjYPos = v.animationTime * movingObjVY;

  v.movingObjects.forEach((element, index) => {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)";
    ctx.fillRect(
      10,
      element.y + movingObjYPos,
      element.img.width,
      element.img.height
    );
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.restore();
  });
}

loop();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Option 3 (mentioned in comments): use translate for animation: here you have the same path the entire time, that's why you only have to add the rectangle once to the path. First you translate the canvas and then draw the rectangle. More on CanvasRenderingContext2D.translate() here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate)

```js
let v = {
  movingObjects: [{
    path: new Path2D(),
    y: 0,
    img: {
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    }
  }],
  animationTime: 0,
  lastFrameTime: 0,
  testingCountOut: 0,
}

const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 400;

function loop() {

  //if (v.testingCountOut >= 10) return;
  let now = Date.now();
  let delta = v.lastFrameTime == 0 ? 0 : (now - v.lastFrameTime) / 1000;
  v.lastFrameTime = now;
  draw(delta);
  //v.testingCountOut++;
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

v.movingObjects.forEach((element, index) => {
    v.movingObjects[index].path.rect(
      10,
      element.y,
      element.img.width,
      element.img.height
    );
  });

function draw(delta) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  v.animationTime = Number(v.animationTime) + Number(delta);
  let movingObjVY = 100;
  let movingObjYPos = v.animationTime * movingObjVY;

  v.movingObjects.forEach((element, index) => {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.translate(0, movingObjYPos)
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,0.5)";
    ctx.fill(v.movingObjects[index].path);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore();
  });
}

loop();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Option 3: you keep the `Path` object with a fixed rectangle, and transform that path by `movingObjYPos` when drawing it